# mysql:how to get the count of unique records which has multiple groupby

Tags: php, mysql

I need the count of the unique records like the following structure

```
DATE      | STATUS |  EMPLOYEE|UNIQUEDATE|UNIQUESTATUS|UNIQUEEMPLOYEE
20-1-2013   active    John          7         3             2
20-1-2013   active    John          7         3             2
20-1-2013   active    Kyle          7         3             1
20-1-2013   inactive  mohan         7         4             1
20-1-2013   inactive  subbu         7         4             3
20-1-2013   inactive  subbu         7         4             3
20-1-2013   inactive  subbu         7         4             3
```

The count is based on the values of generated output

I tried this query :

```
select DATE,STATUS,EMPLOYEE,COUNT(DATE) as DATECOUNT,COUNT(STATUS ) as DATESTATUS ,COUNT(EMPLOYEE) as DATEEMPLOYEE from dailyincome group by DATE,STATUS,EMPLOYEE
```

but the count are same for all the three columns.

Comment: Do you have an SQL Fiddle with some sample data? It's hard for me to see what you're trying to do when all I have is expected output

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select DATE,STATUS,EMPLOYEE,
  COUNT( DISTINCT DATE) as DATECOUNT,
  COUNT( DISTINCT STATUS ) as DATESTATUS ,
  COUNT( DISTINCT EMPLOYEE) as DATEEMPLOYEE 
from dailyincome group by DATE,STATUS,EMPLOYEE
```

I don't have access to your data, so cannot test, but the "distinct" keyword in the COUNT() function should do what you need. We may have to add a `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: i get this following error  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNIQUE DATE) as DATECOUNT from dailyincome

Comment: `UNIQUE` should be `DISTINCT` @sanjeeviraj try that.

Comment: UNIQUE is a special index type... This is completely wrong

Comment: @sanjeeviraj Wait, I think `COUNT( UNIQUE DATE)` because of the space, should be `COUNT( UNIQUEDATE)` but it's unsure what your column names are. One is called `UNIQUEDATE-COUNT` or is it called `UNIQUEDATE`? It's very hard to say. Please edit your question/code as to what they really are. If `UNIQUEDATE-COUNT` what it is, then your query will need ticks `\`` around it, because of the hyphen. You should be using undercores instead of a hyphen.

Comment: Ooops.  `DISTINCT`.   The coffee didn't kick in yet

Comment: @mainstreetmark I know the feeling lol - that's not my downvote btw, just so you know.